# Mysql Like from imploded by commas field

Tags: mysql

if i write:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE themes LIKE '%3%'
```

from the field themes = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5', how to write right '%3' or '3%' or '%3%'

just to check if the user has selected one of those themes

Comment: You should think about making a table associating users and themes by id directly, and not stored as strings.  It would simplify these sorts of queries considerably and make them indexable (much faster).

Answer (score 1):

use `FIND_IN_SET`

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(3, themes) <> 0
```

- [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)